# Why Custom fonts are not applied in Cocoa Application

Tags: swift, macos-catalina, xcode12, custom-font

Im working on Mac OS Application where I need to set custom fonts, so I did following things:
My Xcode version: 12.3

- Added fonts to Application
- Add Application fonts resource path Key to Info.plist and set the value  "."
- Added "New Copy file phase" and provided path Resource->Fonts and added fonts.

In my viewController set those fonts to Label programatically. Like this (titleLabel.font = NSFont(name: "Geogrotesque-Regular", size: 15))

Everything's works fine (fonts getting applied) when I run it at my end. But when I package it through archive or direct through product app folder and send it to my colleague. it doesn't work at their end. It seems very strange things are happening I gone through lot of articles and as per various suggestion I verified my implementation it seems no issue. Then what Im missing here?

Comment: I can't answer your question as to why, but open your application package.  Does it have custom font files in it?

Comment: Yes. it has custom fonts I verified.